# Defined function in python gets rid of variable after finish

Tags: python, python-3.x

Made a module in python. Which is acting as a model of machine code. I have a variable named accumulator.

As in

```
accumulator=0
```

However after I run a function that changes accumlator, as in

```
def function(number):
  accumulator=number
  return
```

and then print the accumulator to show what is in it, it just says `0`.

How can I make a variable that will stay recognised even after the function creating it has finished?

Comment: Did you actually run the function, or just define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `accumulator` is global and the `accumulator=number` inside the function is binding a new local name `accumulator` equal to number. Within `function` you could use `accumulator` but you can't assign to it without use of the `global` statement.

You will get the desired result using:

```
def function(number):
    global accumulator
    accumulator = number
```

Note the return is redundant, as if a Python statement doesn't return, it defaults to returning `None`.